# How to present table in gallery view using jquery or php

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to create a system wherein the users can view records in the database, and its corresponding image. My problem is how to present the table in a fashion similar to that of ebay:
[image]

Here's my code:

```
<?php
require_once('header.php');
?>
<?php $list_items = $db->get_results("SELECT * FROM tbl_products"); ?>
<table border="1">


<?php foreach($list_items as $k=>$li){ ?>

    <tr>    
    <td>
    <p>
    <img src="../img/items/<?php echo $li->str_filename; ?>" width="150px" height="150px">
    </p>
    <p>
    Product Name: <?php echo  $li->str_productName; ?>
    </p>
    <p>
    Category: <?php echo $li->str_category; ?>
    </p>
    <p>
    Quantity: <?php echo $li->dbl_qty; ?>
    </p>
    <p>
    Price: <?php echo $li->dbl_price; ?>
    </p>

    </td>
    </tr>


<?php } ?>  
</table>
```

The current code is outputting the records in list view. Wherein, there's only one record per row. What I want is 4-6 records per row. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
<table border="1">
<?php
$intMaxColumn=4;
$intCountColumn=1;
foreach($list_items as $k=>$li){
  if($intCountColumn==1){
?>
<tr>    
<?php
  }
?>
<td>
<p>
<img src="../img/items/<?php echo $li->str_filename; ?>" width="150px" height="150px">
</p>
<p>
Product Name: <?php echo  $li->str_productName; ?>
</p>
<p>
Category: <?php echo $li->str_category; ?>
</p>
<p>
Quantity: <?php echo $li->dbl_qty; ?>
</p>
<p>
Price: <?php echo $li->dbl_price; ?>
</p>

</td>
<?php
  if($intCountColumn==$intMaxColumn){
    $intCountColumn=1;
?>
</tr>
<?php
  }else{
    $intCountColumn++;
  }
}
?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

add CSS to these tables:

```
float:left;
```

and it will be the same

and do not include one table, but new table for each item. Try this

```
<?php
require_once('header.php');

$list_items = $db->get_results("SELECT * FROM tbl_products");       
foreach($list_items as $k=>$li){ 
?>
<table border="1" style="float:left;">
    <tr>    
    <td>
    <p>
    <img src="../img/items/<?php echo $li->str_filename; ?>" width="150px" height="150px">
    </p>
    <p>
    Product Name: <?php echo  $li->str_productName; ?>
    </p>
    <p>
    Category: <?php echo $li->str_category; ?>
    </p>
    <p>
    Quantity: <?php echo $li->dbl_qty; ?>
    </p>
    <p>
    Price: <?php echo $li->dbl_price; ?>
    </p>

    </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<?php } ?>
```

[demo](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/92888.php)

Comment: If someone has a HUGE & Wide monitor, it will have more the 4~6 products per row

Comment: @ajreal: I think this does not matter for him. We'll see

Comment: Fair enough, FYI, you don't even require the table, wrap each product as one `DIV`

Comment: @ajreal: I won't rewrite it all. It's OP's question: How to make them appear next to the each other. Not to make it better. Yes, it's better to have them in div